# Android Programming Error "No view found for id for fragment " with Google Maps

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So I am using the default Navigation Drawer for my Android Application. What I'm trying to do is linking a button to a fragment I created.

In the fragment I created, I am trying to open up Google Maps.

[image: t1]

Whenever I click on the button however, I get this crash:

[image: t2]

This is the generated error (i have no syntax errors):

```
E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f0d0089 (com.example.x.x:id/mapView) for fragment LocationFragment{35b5044 #1 id=0x7f0d0089}
```

This is the code from the default menu (I try to only put the needed code):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

}
```

In the same default Navigation drawer, we also have the onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) function, that does an action when you click on the menu item, this is where I make the FragmentManager call my LocationFragment:

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();


    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
       fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mapView, new LocationFragment()).commit();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

And here we have the LocationFragment Java class (witht he most important function included):

```
public class LocationFragment extends Fragment {
MapView mMapView;
private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // inflate and return the layout
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.location_fragment, container,
            false);
    mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mMapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    googleMap = mMapView.getMap();
    // latitude and longitude
    double latitude = 17.385044;
    double longitude = 78.486671;

    // create marker
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
            new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello 
    return v;
}
```

The layout file (xml) of the LocationFragment (called location_fragment.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

I do not understand why I get the error, since I have checked all ID's in all classes for maybe 100 times. I seem be stuck here. Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

---

Added activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Have you cleaned your project?

Comment: The error seems to be generated from this line: fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mapView, new LocationFragment()).commit(); What you probably want is  to replace a frame in your activity_main layout with location_fragment.xml. So R.id.mapView has to be replaced with the id of that frame.

Comment: But my activity_main layout is the layout that pops up after my loading screen?

Comment: Your activity_main layout should have a "container" layout,  maybe a FrameLayout, where the previous fragment resides. When you click the button in navigation drawer you want to replace the contents of that container with LocationFragment's layout and thus you will have to use the id of the container as first argument of replace(). I hope you understand that, if not, include your activity_main.xml so I can post a full answer.

Comment: Added it (bottom of question). I do not understand your approach quite exactly since I have noticed it is the default template from the navigation drawer that has created activity_main.xml. Is it obligatory to edit this xml file in order to let my program run smoothly? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

From [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)) , it says: Replace method replaces an existing fragment that was added to a container.

```
public abstract FragmentTransaction replace (int containerViewId, Fragment fragment)
```

Where `containerViewId` is a container. I dont think `MapView` is a container. So instead of:

```
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mapView, new LocationFragment()).commit();
```

It should be:

```
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mapViewContainer, new LocationFragment()).commit();
```

Where `mapViewContainer` is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/mapViewContainer">
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I dont understand your answer actually. You are basically saying to edit the ID of my mapView in the XML file by adding the word 'Container' to it? I did it but It didn't help like I expected

Comment: I did not say adding the word "Container" to the id of the `MapView`. The `mapViewContainer` is the id of the `LinearLayout`, not the id of the `MapView`.

Comment: And this means that I'm using the wrong Layout in my xml?

Comment: No, that means you used the method `replace` in a wrong way!

Comment: Okay thank you very much. Is there another method you would advice me in this particular exercise?